# Messagebox Buttons access in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-programming

I am using timer in my code, lets say when timer stops at 0, messagebox prompts me that you timed out and shows two buttons "RETRY" and "CANCEL". Guide me with the functionality i.e when I press "CANCEL" button on messagebox, it exits the entire windows form.
below is the if condition to the timer_tick event:

```
    int duration = 10;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //shows message that time is up!
       duration--;
       timer_label1.Text = duration.ToString();
       if (duration == 0)
       {
           timer1.Stop();
           MessageBox.Show("You Timed Out", "Oops", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

       } 
    }

    private void start_game_button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Lns.png)

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far, so we can help you..

Comment: int duration = 10;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //shows message that time is up!
            duration--;
           timer_label1.Text= duration.ToString();
           if (duration == 0)
           {
               timer1.Stop();
               MessageBox.Show("You Timed Out", "Oops", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

           } 
        }

        private void start_game_button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }

Comment: You can edit your original post. Long code in comment area does not really help.

Comment: sorry for the bad code formatting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with `MessageBox` and take a different action depending on the button clicked, one must assign the result of the `Show` call to a variable. `Show` returns a `DialogResult` value which you can use to determine which button was clicked.

```
var retryOrCancel = MessageBox.Show(
    text: "You Timed Out",
    caption: "Oops",
    buttons: MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel,
    icon: MessageBoxIcon.Stop
);

switch (retryOrCancel)
{
    case DialogResult.Cancel:
    this.Close();
    break;
    case DialogResult.Retry:
    StartGame();
    break;
}

private void start_game_button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartGame();
}

private void StartGame() 
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this below code:

```
var result =  MessageBox.Show(
              "You Timed Out",
              "Oops",
              MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel,
              MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) {
    this.Close();
}
```